# How do I set a distribution key or key group for Netezza in IBM Data Architect?

Tags: netezza

I am asked to pre-set some distribution key or key groups for deployment into Netezza.
We are using IBM Data Architect as our data modeling tool.

Where in the logical data model can I change the distribution key type and possible add columns to the key group?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be version dependent, but the distribution key should be found in the **physical** data model as a property of the table in IBM Data Architect.

Comment: that's the piece we were missing.  we don't normally save the PDM's.  only LDM's.  looks like we need to now.